# Update modified files - git

Tags: git, github

I changed 2 files on my project..
so I command:

```
git add .

git status
```

I get this:

[image]

so I command:

```
git commit
git push origin master
```

and I get the message: `Everything-up-to-date`

Why the 2 files weren't updated?

Tks in advance

Comment: Updated on Github I guess?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That would be because you're trying to push to `origin master`, while you made your changes in the `v01` branch. You should either push to a `v01` remote, or else merge your changes into `master` before pushing.

Answer (score 2):

```
git push origin master
```

will push your (local branch) *master* to origin. The local is the first part in the *<refspec>* parameter:

```
git push [<repository> [<refspec>...]]
```

(this is a simplified synopsis of the command you use)

You push to the *"`origin`"* repository (a remote) and you push the *<refspec>*. In your case that *refspec* (Specify what destination ref to update with what source object) is *"`master`"*.

What does it mean if you use *"`master`"* as *refspec* alone? In your case it's what the man-page calls the *"source object <src>"*. And further explaining:

> The <src> is often the name of the branch you would want to push, but it can be any arbitrary "SHA-1 expression", such as master~4 or HEAD

So you told to push the (HEAD of the) *master* branch to the *origin* repository.

And git told you that *master* on *origin* is already up-to-date, which means, it (*master*) is the same on *origin* as it is in your (local) repository.

Question perhaps is, why you wrote *master* in there when you wanted to push a different `<src>` probably. But for that you would need to add more context, otherwise this would be guessing.

---

Reference:

```
$ git push --help
```

Opens the manpage in your webbrowser (as hyptertext document, very comfortable) if you use git bash (mingw, e.g. on Windows) or shows the manpage (e.g. on Linux) which is fast as hell in shell.

Comment: He is on a different branch. That's why master is up to date it seems